# dr["strImage"] = uploadFImage.HasFile; Is False -Upload part not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

(ASP.NET project) I have a **File Upload** control and I am using `Trigger` for my grid view.
File upload part is not working and I am always getting **false** value, not displayed uploaded image name,   `dr["strImage"] = uploadFImage.HasFile;` 
How can I fix it?

Its a detail save   #region Detail Save1

```
     private DataTable CreateDetailSave()
        {
            DataTable dtDetailSave1 = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dc1;
            dc1 = new DataColumn("intArticleDetailId");
            dtDetailSave1.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dc1 = new DataColumn("intSectionId");
            dtDetailSave1.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dc1 = new DataColumn("intCompoundId");
            dtDetailSave1.Columns.Add(dc1);            
            dc1 = new DataColumn("decSectionWeight");
            dtDetailSave1.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dc1 = new DataColumn("intMessageId");
            dtDetailSave1.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dc1 = new DataColumn("strImage");
            dtDetailSave1.Columns.Add(dc1);



            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvArticle.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dr = dtDetailSave1.NewRow();

                Label lblintArticleDetailId = (Label)row.FindControl("lblArticleDetailId");
                Label lblSectionId = (Label)row.FindControl("lblSectionId");
                DropDownList ddlCompound = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlCompoundId");
                TextBox txtdecSectionWeighte = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtdecSectionWeighte");
                DropDownList intMessage = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlMessage");

                FileUpload uploadFImage = (FileUpload)row.FindControl("uploadFImage");

                dr["intArticleDetailId"] = CurrentMode == "Add" ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(lblintArticleDetailId.Text);


                dr["intSectionId"] = Convert.ToInt32(lblSectionId.Text);
                dr["intCompoundId"] = ddlCompound.SelectedValue;
                dr["decSectionWeight"] = txtdecSectionWeighte.Text.Trim() != "" ? Convert.ToDecimal(txtdecSectionWeighte.Text.Trim()) : 0;
                dr["intMessageId"] = intMessage.SelectedValue;
                dr["strImage"] = uploadFImage.HasFile;


                dtDetailSave1.Rows.Add(dr);

            }

            return dtDetailSave1;

        }
        #endregion

      #region Create Article table
        private void createArticleDataTable()
        {
            if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("intArticleDetailId", typeof(int)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("intSectionId", typeof(int)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("strSectionName", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("intCompoundId", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("decSectionWeight", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("intMessageId", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("uploadFImage", typeof(string)));

            }

            gvArticle.DataSource = dt;
            gvArticle.DataBind();
        }        
        #endregion

        #region Compound Grid - Add empty row
        private void ArticleGridAddEmptyRow(int newId)
        {
            DataRow newDr = null;
            newDr = dt.NewRow();
            newDr["intArticleDetailId"] = 1;
            newDr["intSectionId"] = 1;
            newDr["strSectionName"] = "";
            newDr["intCompoundId"] = "";
            newDr["decSectionWeight"] = "";
            newDr["intMessageId"] = "";
            newDr["strImage"] = "";


            dt.Rows.Add(newDr);

            if (dtArticleDetails == null || dtArticleDetails.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                dtArticleDetails = dt;
            }
            else
            {
                dtArticleDetails.Merge(dt);

                gvArticle.DataSource = dt;
                gvArticle.DataBind();
            }

        }
        #endregion

 protected void gvArticle_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {


            }
            else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {


                { 


                }

                DataTable CompoundCode = clsArticle.CompoundDataForGrid("");

                DropDownList ddlCompoundId = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCompoundId");
                if (ddlCompoundId != null)
                {
                    ddlCompoundId.DataTextField = "Compound Code";
                    ddlCompoundId.DataValueField = "Compound Id";
                    ddlCompoundId.DataSource = CompoundCode;
                    ddlCompoundId.DataBind();

                    string country = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlCompoundId") as DropDownList).Text;
                    ddlCompoundId.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = true;
                }


                DataTable MsgCode = clsArticle.MessageDataForGrid("");

                DropDownList ddlMessage = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlMessage");
                if (ddlMessage != null)
                {
                    ddlMessage.DataTextField = "Message Name";
                    ddlMessage.DataValueField = "Message Id";
                    ddlMessage.DataSource = MsgCode;
                    ddlMessage.DataBind();

                    ddlMessage.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));
                    string country = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlMessage") as DropDownList).Text;
                    ddlMessage.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = true;
                }



                //}


            }
        }



        protected void gvArticle_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            FileUpload uploadFImage = (FileUpload)gvArticle.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("uploadFImage");
             System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image  btnViewFImage = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)gvArticle.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl(" btnViewFImage");







            //if (e.RowIndex[0].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            //{
            //    //FileUpload uploadFImage = (FileUpload)e.Row.FindControl("uploadFImage");


                try
                {
                    Session["FrontStyleImageUrl"] = null;

                    if (uploadFImage.HasFile)
                    {
                        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                        string sGuid = guid.ToString();
                        //string FrontImagefilename = Path.GetFileName(uploadFImage.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string FrontImagefilename = Path.GetFileName(uploadFImage.FileName);

                        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FrontImagefilename);

                        string mExtenstion;
                        string mFileName;

                        mFileName = fi.Name;
                        mExtenstion = fi.Extension;
                        mFileName = mFileName.Replace(mExtenstion, "");  // Removes Extestion


                        //string FrontImagetargetPath = Server.MapPath((@"~\Uploaded Images\Styles") + "\\" + sGuid + FrontImagefilename);
                        string FrontImagetargetPath = Server.MapPath((@"~\Uploaded Images") + "\\" + mFileName + "_" + sGuid + mExtenstion);

                        //string savedPath = "~/Uploaded Images/Styles/" + sGuid + FrontImagefilename;
                        string savedPath = "~/Uploaded Images/" + mFileName + "_" + sGuid + mExtenstion;

                        Stream FrontImagestrm = uploadFImage.PostedFile.InputStream;
                        var FrontImagetargetFile = FrontImagetargetPath;
                        GenerateThumbnailsForFrontImage(0.5, FrontImagestrm, FrontImagetargetFile);


                        Session["FrontStyleImageUrl"] = savedPath;
                        btnViewFImage.Enabled = true;
                        btnViewFImage.ImageUrl = savedPath;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }


            //}
        }
        private void GenerateReportThumbnailsForImage(double scaleFactor, Stream sourcePath, string targetPath)
        {

            using (var imageF = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(sourcePath))
            {

                //var newWidth = (int)(imageF.Width * scaleFactor);

                //var newHeight = (int)(imageF.Height * scaleFactor);

                // can given width of image as we want
                var newWidth = 100;
                // can given height of image as we want
                var newHeight = 70;



                var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
                thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                thumbGraph.DrawImage(imageF, imageRectangle);
                thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath, imageF.RawFormat);
            }

        }

        private void GenerateThumbnailsForFrontImage(double scaleFactor, Stream sourcePath, string targetPath)
        {

            using (var imageF = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(sourcePath))
            {

                //var newWidth = (int)(imageF.Width * scaleFactor);

                //var newHeight = (int)(imageF.Height * scaleFactor);

                // can given width of image as we want
                var newWidth = 400;
                // can given height of image as we want
                var newHeight = 340;



                var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
                thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                thumbGraph.DrawImage(imageF, imageRectangle);
                thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath, imageF.RawFormat);
            }

        }

    }
```

**ASPX**

```
 <asp:FileUpload runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  ID="uploadFImage" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strImage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>

                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField> 


                                                                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">                                                                
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>


  <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Uploaded Images/Default.png" runat="server" ID="btnViewFImage"  Width="40" Height="40"/>

                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: add the cs and aspx code, without it we can't see if there's a problem, and S.O. is getting late serving our crystal balls, mine has a delay of 3 years...

Comment: what you are expecting from FileUpload to `dr["strImage"]`

Comment: Sir @un-lucky updated my Question

Comment: Good but the updates doesn't have the answer for my question, What you are expecting in `dr["strImage"]` is that the path of uploaded file?

Comment: `<asp:FileUpload runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"  ID="uploadFImage" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strImage") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"/>` im getting this